# How to delete 1st column in SQL Database using R

Tags: sql, r, rodbc, vsql

```
This is a simple example
Basket                                        

rownames fruit       quantities     
1        apple           3
2        orange          4
3        tomatoes        6
4        watermelon      7
5        durian          8
```

How do I remove the rownames using R in SQL, sorry I am new to R and SQL.

Comment: What is R in your case ? I dont understand your question. Can you explained bit ?

Comment: @ajay, Try to hover with your mouse above the `r` tag and find out

Comment: R language, A software I use is called Rstudio, is there a way to delete the rownames column which is in SQLDatabase

Comment: How are you connecting to the sql database?

Comment: @mgriebe library(RODBC) ch <- odbcConnect("vertica", uid="dbadmin", pwd="123"  )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that I cannot test this on my machine.

You can try setting `rownames=FALSE` when you `sqlFetch` the table.  That may solve your problem.

But, to solve the problem in the title, you can do:

```
BasketDF<-sqlFetch(ch,"Basket")
NewBasket<-BasketDF[,-1]
sqlUpdate(ch,NewBasket,"Basket")
```